# How to synchronize request send time across different nodes in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, distributed

I need to do stress test with JMeter, the requirement is to send a http request with 1000 threads at the same time (ramp-up=0). If I use single node, this can be achieved by synchronized timer. But how to achive that in multiple JMeter slaves?

For example, suppose I have 2 slaves: A and B, A has 500 threads, B has 500 threads. In slave A, the 500 requests can be controlled to send at the same time, same situation also happens in slave B. But is there any way to make all 1000 requests are sent at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synchronizing timer only works within one JVM as per [reference documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer).

1000 threads is very doable without using master/slave load testing provided you respect [best-practices](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/), so this would be an option.

Alternatively, I am not sure why you need such timer, if you just want to guarantee certain hits per second, you could go for:

- [Precise Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

If you want to increase your knowledge of performance testing and JMeter, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) written by three developers of the JMeter team will help you.